# Bluetooth Printing from Android not working as expected

Tags: java, android, printing, bluetooth, stream

I have been using the following code to send data to a bluetooth printer:

```
try {
    BluetoothAdapter oBluetoothAdapter  = BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter();
    BluetoothDevice  oDispositivo       = oBluetoothAdapter.getRemoteDevice(cMAC);

    Method oMethod = oDispositivo.getClass().getMethod("createRfcommSocket",new Class[] { int.class });
    oSocket = (BluetoothSocket) oMethod.invoke(oDispositivo, Integer.valueOf(1));
    oSocket.connect();

    btoutputstream = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(oSocket.getOutputStream(),"ISO_8859_1"));

    // Enviamos el mensaje
    int off = 0;

    while(off < nLength){

        btoutputstream.write(msg,off,nBloque);
        btoutputstream.flush();

        Thread.sleep(nSleep);

        off += nBloque;

        if((off + nBloque) > nLength) nBloque = nLength - off;  
    }

    btoutputstream.flush();

}catch(Exception e){
    return cFail + " || Exception: " + e.toString();
}
finally{
    try{
        if(btoutputstream != null) btoutputstream.close();
        if(oSocket != null) oSocket.close();
    }catch(Exception e2){
        return e2.toString();
    }
}
```

The problem is that this code is not working on the same printer with a new Bluetooth device. It prints the first block of code and it doesn't print anymore.

So I've been looking for a way to make it work, and I ended up using this:

```
public static String BluetoothPrint()
{
    try{
    mBluetoothAdapter = BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter();
    mmDevice    = mBluetoothAdapter.getRemoteDevice(cMac);

    UUID uuid = UUID.fromString("00001101-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb");
    mmSocket = mmDevice.createRfcommSocketToServiceRecord(uuid);
    mmSocket.connect();
    mmOutputStream = mmSocket.getOutputStream();
    mmInputStream = mmSocket.getInputStream();

    beginListenForData();

    mmOutputStream.write(cText.getBytes());

} catch(Exception e) {
    return "error: " + e.toString();
} finally {
    //      try{
        //          stopWorker = true;
        //          mmOutputStream.close();
        //          mmInputStream.close();
        //          mmSocket.close();
        //      } catch(Exception e) {
        //          return "error: " + e.toString()
        //      }
}

return "ok";
}

public static void beginListenForData(){
    try {
    final Handler handler = new Handler();

    // This is the ASCII code for a newline character
    final byte delimiter = 10;

    stopWorker = false;
    readBufferPosition = 0;
    readBuffer = new byte[1024];

    workerThread = new Thread(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            while (!Thread.currentThread().isInterrupted()
            && !stopWorker) {

                try {

                    int bytesAvailable = mmInputStream.available();
                    if (bytesAvailable > 0) {
                        byte[] packetBytes = new byte[bytesAvailable];
                        mmInputStream.read(packetBytes);
                        for (int i = 0; i < bytesAvailable; i++) {
                            byte b = packetBytes[i];
                            if (b == delimiter) {
                                byte[] encodedBytes = new byte[readBufferPosition];
                                System.arraycopy(readBuffer, 0,
                                encodedBytes, 0,
                                encodedBytes.length);
                                final String data = new String(
                                encodedBytes, "US-ASCII");
                                readBufferPosition = 0;

                                handler.post(new Runnable() {
                                    public void run() {
                                        //myLabel.setText(data);
                                    }
                                });
                            } else {
                                readBuffer[readBufferPosition++] = b;
                            }
                        }
                    }

                } catch (Exception ex) {
                    stopWorker = true;
                }

            }
        }
    });

    workerThread.start();
} catch (NullPointerException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
} catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

}

This code is working correct, but my main problem is that the printing is very slow (up to 1:30 min, while before it was printing in 15-20 seconds). I realized that it is going slow because of the empty lines. The printer is slow while printing them, but there's no problem with the lines which have text.

So I'm looking for a way to speed up that code, but I'm stuck. I tried to make the read buffer bigger, but doesn't seem to do nothing.

Comment: "The printer is slow while printing them" - that seems to be a printers problem and not something that can be solve on StackOverflow

Comment: I don't think that is the problem, as the same printer with the old bluetooth device and the first code I posted, is printing with no problem. That's why I'm guessing the code can be optimized in any way.

Comment: I've thought that by "bluetooth device" you mean a printer, and you're using a new printer now. My bad.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've finally managed to get it working properly.

In the text that I was sending to print, the empty lines just had a linebreak (CRLF). As the other ones were printing OK, I tried to add a character on the empty lines (a space, so it prints the same) and it doesn't print slow anymore. I don't know what's the reason of this, but it is working faster, just like before the bluetooth changed.